# New object from existing object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to create a new object from existing object using javascript.

I have object `obj` and array `arr`, from that need to create a object in the expected output format.

```
var result =getObj("en", obj);

function getObj(lang, obj){
  var newobj = {};
  newobj['url'] = "/"+ lang +"/"+obj[lang].map(e=>e.faq);
  var s ={lang: lang, url: newobj.url};
  newobj['links']=[s];
  return newobj;
}
```

```
    var obj={
      "en": [{
      "faq": "faq",
      "about": "about"
      }],
      "hi": [{
      "faq": "aksar-poochhe-jaane-vaale",
      "about": "hamaare-baare"
      }]    
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
getObj("en", obj);
//expected result
{
  "url": "/en/faq",
  "links": [
     { lang: 'en', url: '/en/faq' },
     { lang: 'hi', url: '/hi/aksar-poochhe-jaane-vaale' }
   ]
 },{
  "url": "/en/about",
  "links": [
     { lang: 'en', url: '/en/about' },
     { lang: 'hi', url: '/hi/hamaare-baare' }
   ]
 }

getObj("hi", obj);
//expected result
 {
  "url": "/hi/aksar-poochhe-jaane-vaale",
  "links": [
     { lang: 'en', url: '/en/faq' },
     { lang: 'hi', url: '/hi/aksar-poochhe-jaane-vaale' }
   ]
 },{
  "url": "/hi/hamaare-baare",
  "links": [
     { lang: 'en', url: '/en/about' },
     { lang: 'hi', url: '/hi/hamaare-baare' }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: checkout Object.assign, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Your expected output isn't exactly valid. Do you mean an array of two objects? And you'll need at least two loops (or equivalent iteration methods) to get that kind of nested output.

Comment: The values of `obj.en` and `obj.hi` are arrays with a single object in them. Can there be multiple objects there, and what should the result look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested loops. The main loop returns the top-level array of objects, and the inner loop creates the `links` array within each object.

```js
function getObj(lang, obj) {
  const langObj = obj[lang][0];
  return Object.keys(langObj).map(key => ({
    url: `/${lang}/${langObj[key]}`,
    links: Object.keys(obj).map(l => ({
      lang: l,
      url: `/${l}/${obj[l][0][key]}`
    }))
  }));
}

var obj = {
  "en": [{
    "faq": "faq",
    "about": "about"
  }],
  "hi": [{
    "faq": "aksar-poochhe-jaane-vaale",
    "about": "hamaare-baare"
  }]
};

console.log(getObj("en", obj));
console.log(getObj("hi", obj));
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but the  `url` should be  ` "/hi/aksar-poochhe-jaane-vaale", "/hi/hamaare-baare" as in expected output`

Comment: can you pleas help

Comment: Fixed it, I was using the wrong variable in the first `url` property.